# bitmap, work with get dark colors

Tags: android, colors, bitmap

in my application I have to work on the individual pixels of an image.
first of all, I give the image in grayscale with this code

```
private Bitmap BiancoNero(Bitmap originalBitmap) {
        ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
        colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);

        ColorMatrixColorFilter colorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(
                colorMatrix);

        Bitmap blackAndWhiteBitmap = originalBitmap.copy(
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
         paint.setColorFilter(colorMatrixFilter);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(blackAndWhiteBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(blackAndWhiteBitmap, 0, 0, paint);

        return blackAndWhiteBitmap;
    }
```

after that, drawing a matrix with only 0 and 1 (0 white, 1 black)
with the following control

```
if(colore==-1)
        matrice[i][j] = 0; //zero is for white
                                else if(colore == -16777216)
                                        matrice[i][j] = 1; //black pixel
                                else
                                        matrice[i][j] =0; //other shades of gray
```

How do I get to pick up the nuances of dark gray?
that is, when we consider white  0% and black 100%, I want to find all the colors that are above 66%
I just put in the  `if> color = 5592405`  (which is equivalent to -16777216 / 3 )
would it work?

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is gray as you say then R = G = B values.

Let's take the least significant "byte" and test based on it.

```
int c = colore & 0xFF;
```

c supposed to be a value between 0 and 255 inclusive.

66%:

```
if ((float)c > 255.0f*0.66f)
```

it's easier to work with small numbers. try it and post results.